# Serialize form as json, without ajax

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to automate requests to some 3rd party site, which does not have an API, and no Access-control-Allow-Origin. So no ajax possible, my only option is to reproduce the site's forms and post them.

But on some forms, the site uses ajax with JSON encoding, and it seems the same data in url-encoded format is not accepted.

`Application/json` is not an accepted value of form's `encType` or `formEncType` attributes (thus is ignored when set). I've also tried building the object and serializing it in a hidden field (with encType as plain text), but a browser will ignore inputs without name, and putting a name will defeat the trick of passing a value as the request's content.

Is there a way in javascript to tell the browser to encode the data as json before sending it sychronously?

Comment: That sounds like a site that was explicitly designed to prevent cross-domain posting.

Comment: I'm more inclined to think it was badly designed. If it were done purposefully, they'd have put anti-XSRF tokens of some sort.

Comment: You might be able to put *some* of the json in the name field, and the rest in the value field, so when you use enctype text/plain and the browser automatically adds a = after the name, it forms a valid json string...

Comment: @Adam, that's an idea I need to test right away

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe: you're a genius, your idea works fine. You might want to write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to put some of the json in the name field, and the rest in the value field, so when you use enctype text/plain and the browser automatically adds a = after the name, it forms a valid json string.

The HTML spec says text/plain forms are made by writing the name, then a =, then the value, followed by a newline. So if you split the json on the = and put the first part as the name and the second part as the value, it just might form a valid string that the server accepts.

Comment: There's no '=' in my string, but I just add a dummy parameter to the data to account for it, and it works fine.